# Responsive img css with a twist

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm trying to get an image (img) to fill all available space inside a div BUT also I want the img itself to be inside an equaly sized container with position:relative so that I can place markers on the image with absolute position.

I have tried using div background-image and that works perfect except that my markers positions are out of place (of course) since the parent div is not the same size.

And with  I get the markers to work perfect but then the image doesn't scale with parent container.

I need the image to behave like background-image but I also need the parent container to be same size.

Here I have 2 pens showing what I mean.
First one with background-image. [pen:background-image](https://codepen.io/StaffMan78/pen/rNrmBYW)

```
body {    height: 90vh;
    background: aliceblue;}
.page-inner {
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.main-container {
      width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 2em 1em 2em 1em;
  background:yellow;
  
}

.working-area {
  position:relative;
}

.work-item {
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
  background:white;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
    <div class="page-inner">
        <h3 class="" >Some text</h3>
            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="working-area" style="height:100%;width:100%;background-position: center;background-image:url('');background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat">
                   <div class="work-item">X</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div>
            <h3 class="" >Some text again</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Second one with img: [pen:img](https://codepen.io/StaffMan78/pen/zYLwORw)

```
body {    height: 90vh;
    background: aliceblue;}
.page-inner {
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.main-container {
      width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 2em 1em 2em 1em;
  background:yellow;
  
}

.main-container img {
  width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.working-area {
  position:relative;
}

.work-item {
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
  background:white;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

<div class="page-inner">
        <h3 class="" >Some text</h3>
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="working-area">
                <img src="" style="" />
                <div class="work-item">X</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3 class="" >Some text again</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to combine these 2 into one :-) I need full scaling of image at the same time as I need to get image size and position relative so I can place my markers.

The image can be in any size and the screen can be resized at any time, so I need a solution that really is responsive.

thanks!

I have tried width:100%;height:auto; nad like 200 other different things. I have also started to calculate the image aspect-ratio and have a hidden img and then manually, with js, calculate each marker pos in %  based on parent div size.

The solution needs to work with all img sizes and aspect ratios. Users uploads image so I don't know what sizes will come.

I have also tried to position the image with full width and height and then used transform: scale to make it fit the parent div with lots of calculations in js.

But there has to be an easier way :-)

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand correctly, you want the image to cover its container element.  i.e. it may be  scaled up or down and cropped either at the sides or top/bottom. Is that right? I think you will end up with some JS, but not much. Is that acceptable?

Comment: hi, almost right. Yes I want the image to be able to scale up and down to fit parent div. Either height or width should always hit the limit. I don't want ever to crop the image. It should always show full image.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How are the parent element(s) sized?

Comment: I've edit the original post to also include the css. Everything is also in the pens (link)

Comment: I think you just have to plod through doing some calculations - some JS will be needed to find the actual dimension of the containing element and make a child that has the right aspect ratio. You can then position the overlays using % offsets from the left and top edges of the image (which you might as well measure with a ruler). Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Yes I was afraid of that. I know how to do it with calculations, but I was hoping to find a solution that was more "out of the box". But thanks a lot for taking the time to answer!!

Comment: I think % positioning is the best you can do - at least it will be responsive (or, I've just done the ruler measuring and got the CSS to calculate the %s).